# How do i ensure that my textarea value should always contain the word "india" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

How do i ensure that my textarea value should always contain the word "india" in javascript?

Actually i want to validate the textarea so that the user should always the word "india" in that.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now to be clear, you want the `textarea` to only contain *"india"*?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `blur` event which is invoked when the user removes focus from the `textarea`.

```
<textarea onblur="return validate(this);"></textarea>

var reg = /\bindia\b/im;
function validate(textArea) {
    // case-insensitive search for "india"
    if (!reg.test(textArea.value)) {
        alert("Where's India?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pandion, User can give anything but it should contain the word "india"

Comment: Ok Chaos, thank you for your code and your time. Tomorrow i will come with some other questions. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea onchange='if(this.value.indexOf("india") == -1) this.value = "";'></textarea>
```